# Transforming every training points without using dataloaders

Tags: python, pytorch

I just found out that even though `torchvision.dataset.MNIST` accepts the `transformer` parameter, ...

```py
transform = transforms.compose(
    [transforms.ToTensor(), transforms.Normalize((0.5,), (0.5,))]
)
mnist_trainset = datasets.mnist(
    root="mnist", train=True, download=True, transform=transform
)
```

...the value obtained from the `mnist_trainset.data` variable is still not transformed (please observe that the data in the range of (0, 255) should be normalised to (-1, 1) regarding the `transformer`'s behaviour).

```py
[102] mnist_testset.data[0].min()
tensor(0, dtype=torch.uint8)

[103] mnist_testset.data[0].max()
tensor(255, dtype=torch.uint8)
```

I tried calling `mnist_trainset.transform` over `mnist_trainset.data`, but the output shape is not what I intended

```
[104] mnist_testset.data.shape
torch.Size([10000, 28, 28])

[105] transform(mnist_testset.data).shape
torch.Size([3, 28, 28])

# Should be [10000, 28, 28] as identical to the original data.
```

I can use the `DataLoader` to load the entire training set and set the shuffling to `False`, but I think it's too overkilling. What is the best way to transform the *entire* `mnist_testset` using the defined `transformer` object, in order to obtain the intended transformed image, without having to manually transform it one-by-one?

Comment: There is no need for `ToTensor()` (I suppose that's what is in your code) in `transform` if you are passing `data` field of `MNIST`, as it's already a `torch.tensor`. Could you try removing it from `transform` and passing in `tensor` unsqueezed in the first dimension like this: `transform(mnist_testset.data.unsqueeze(dim=1))`?

Comment: Thank you! Yes, `ToTensor()` is in my code, capitalised, I accidentally lower caps all the text when I pasted it here. Removing the `transform` and running your code results into `TypeError: tensor is not a torch image.`.

Comment: The MNIST dataset converts each sample to a `PIL.Image` before applying transforms in the `MNIST.__getitem__` so the `ToTensor` is necessary if you sample the dataset using `mnist_testset[idx]` or if you use a dataloader.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Transforms are invoked when you sample the dataset using its `__getitem__` method. So you could do something like the following to get all the transformed data.

```
imgs_transformed = []
for img, label in mnist_testset:
    imgs_transformed.append(img[0,:,:])
```

or using list comprehension

```
imgs_transformed = [img[0,:,:] for img, label in mnist_testset]
```

---

If you want to turn this into one big tensor you can use `torch.stack`

```
data_transformed = torch.stack(imgs_transformed, dim=0)
```

Comment: Regarding this answer, I hoped there would exist some "Pythonista", one-liner code to do this job. Unfortunately, there seemed to be one. Another option is to use `DataLoader` with size set to the dataset's length and no shuffling as mentioned. Thank you for your kind answer anyway!

Comment: Yes the most obvious way is to use a dataloader, my understanding from the original question was that you wanted a solution which didn't rely on a dataloader.